# Auto scroll UICollectionView when I scroll UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, scrollview, swift4.2

I have a horizontal `CollectionView` on top and `TableView` under it 
I want as I scroll `TableView` my `CollectionView` should scroll and animate along with to some level I have achieved with `scrollItemTo` but `CollectionView` scrolling to slow but I want it working as it is working in **uberEats** iOS app in restaurant items list details  and same is working in **urbanClap** app

*It's like moving a view cell by cell as table view section header reach top*

Comment: Add the collectionview in tableview header or add it in first table view cell

Comment: Add the code that you have used till now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The uber eats app functionality that you're referring works like: whenever a particular section of `tableView` reaches the top, that particular `collectionViewCell` is selected.

As evident from the above statement,

**number of items in `collectionView` = number of sections in `tableView`**

You can achieve the solution to this particular problem by tracking the top visible section index of `tableView` and then selecting the `collectionViewCell` at that particular index, i.e.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView === self.tableView {
        if
            let topSectionIndex = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.map({ $0.section }).sorted().first,
            let selectedCollectionIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.row,
            selectedCollectionIndex != topSectionIndex {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: topSectionIndex, section: 0)
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Changing `collectionViewCell` color on selection:**

Create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and override `**isSelected**` property to handle selected and un-selected state, i.e.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2588235438, green: 0.7568627596, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
            } else {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You won't need to manually update the `backgroundColor` of cell elsewhere after this.

Comment: my cell color does not change when I scroll to down it only changes when I scroll up

Comment: How are you implementing the cell coloraturas change logic?

Comment: func changeCellColor(indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let collectIndex = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
            let cell = collectIndex as! CollectionViewCell
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                cell.containerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                cell.cellLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: and i call it here      
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
            
            changeCellColor(indexPath: indexPath)

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle selected and un-selected state of `collectionViewCell`.

Comment: can I get any other way of communicating  **meetheiosdeveloper@gmail.com** so i can share code

Comment: from were isSelected  will be set true or false

Comment: It will be handled automatically by the `collectionView` when a cell is selected/unselected.

Comment: thanks you are my hero
i want one more help when i select on a row of the section then that section name in collectionView mov to centre an get selected

Comment: You can turn off the `isUserInteractionEnabled` of `collectionView` in case you don't want to select the `collectionViewCell` manually.

Comment: no, I also want to when I select on collection cell it should scroll to section in tableview and that is working fine with **scrollToRow**

I also want to scroll the collectionView to an item when I press a section in tableView and that collectionview cell to be selected

Comment: Is there any issue you are facing with that?

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper I think you're just busy in clearing your doubts and not considering appreciate the one helping you. And that's kind of a bit rude on your part. And for your further requirements, I advise you to try them yourself first and then ask in case you face any issues.

Comment: I really appreciate you  bro but when to try to vote up it says your reputation is below 15 I wish I can reward you 100 bucks if I can I really happy and thankful with your help thanks bro

Comment: There is a tick button on the left that you can click to accept the answer.

Comment: when i vote up **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score**

i am new to stackover flow pardon me if i did anything wrong

Comment: i did it bro i wish i can press it 1000 times

Answer (score 1):

You can implemement `scrollViewDidScroll` of `UIScrollViewDelegate` for your tableView then manually scroll your `UICollectionView` from there

```
class XYZ: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

     func viewDidLoad(){
         super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.delegate = self
     }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
         let tableView = scrollView //assuming the only scrollView.delegate you conform to is the tableVeiw

         collectionView.contentOffset = someMappingFrom(tableView.contentOffset) //or some other scrolling mechanism (scrollToItem)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change selection on scrollViewDidScroll.

I've attached the link to repo for the same code

[Github Repo for solution](https://github.com/Sudarshan7993/CollectionWithTableView)